# How to deal with reference data-members in the assignment operator, and copy constructor?

Tags: c++, reference

I have following class

```
class TVData
{
  private:
  int ID;
  Monitor& monitor;
  string pName;

}
```

I need to implement the *assignment operator*, and a *copy-constructor* usable with this class.

- How do I handle reference members, in this case `TVData::monitor`, in such scenario?

Comment: What semantics do you want the copy constructor and assignment operator to have?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reassign a reference, so if you need it to change in the assignment operator then you should make it a pointer - assignment can then be done as usual with `=`, although it's still encouraged to use an initialiser list in the copy constructor...

```
TVData(const TVData& rhs)
  : ID(rhs.ID), p_monitor(rhs.p_monitor), pNmae(rhs.pName)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

**INTRODUCTION**

To correctly assign a data member variabled declares as being a reference you will need to make use of a [*member initialization list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in your constructor (both in your *default-*, and your *copy-constructor*).

The problem with an overload assignment operator is that since a reference cannot be bound to a new entity after it has been initialized (and it must be initialized) you cannot change what this reference is referring to after you have created your `TVData`.

If you'd want to be able to change what the reference refers to consider using pointers instead of references.

---

**SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#include <iostream>
```

```
struct Obj {
  Obj (int& r)
    : ref (r)
  { }

  Obj (Obj const& src)
    : ref (src.ref) 
  { }

  Obj& operator= (Obj const& src) {
    // we cannot reassign what `ref` is refering to,
    // but we can at least assign the value of `src.ref`
    // to `this->ref`

    ref = src.ref; // note: does not make `ref` refer to `src.ref`
  }

  int& ref;
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int some_val = 0, some_other_val = 100;

  Obj a (some_val);
  Obj b (a); // copy `a`
  Obj c (some_other_val);

  b = c;

  b.ref += 23;

  std::cout << "some_val: " << some_val << std::endl;
}
```

```
some_val: 123
```

Answer (score 0):

reference are not copiable nor movable, you have to fallback to pointer or [reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using (non-const) references as class members is fairly dangerous because in that case you have to guarantee somehow that the referenced object will outlive the class's instance referencing it.

Secondly, you can implement the copy constructor for such a class but you can't make assignment because C++ references are not rebindable.

In order to manage this, you might prefer using shared_ptr/unique_ptr depending on the assignment semantics of your class (whether it should share the owned Monitor or pass the ownership). If you're not owning it, then weak_ptr (std:: or boost::) is your best bet.